# Setting up SVN with Plesk

Tags: svn

I'm setting up a new dev webserver that is on Cent OS 6 with Plesk 10.4. I've had a look around and can't find anything about an SVN module for Plesk so am thinking of just installing SVN and manually setting up each site as a repo.

Is there anything I need to take into consideration when doing this such as permissions/usernames? Or is it okay to just go ahead and treat it like any other installation of SVN?

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've managed to set up SVN on this server. I'm leaving this here in case anybody else wants to see how I did it.

I assumed that you don't need to do anything special just because Plesk is on the system and this turned out to be true.

I followed the instructions [here](http://alexduan.com/2011/08/17/centos-6-subversion-svnssh/) to install and setup svn and then the instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/159254/setting-up-svn-on-a-hosted-server) to set up the repos.

NOTE: If you use the instructions from the first link then when it comes to checking out your code remotely then the correct url would be `svn+ssh://username@yourhost/yourproject` as the wrapper script automatically looks in /var/svn/repos/

Comment: First link is dead, unfortunately.